# SQL Server: How to unpivot from pivoted table back to a self referencing table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

I've looked at examples from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15 but I couldn't seem to find samples of what I'm trying to do.

I'm wondering if there's a way to unpivot from this:

```
+----+------------+--------+--------+--------+
| Id | Level0     | Level1 | Level2 | Level3 |
+----+------------+--------+--------+--------+
| 0  | TMI        |        |        |        |
+----+------------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1  | TMI        | A      |        |        |
+----+------------+--------+--------+--------+
| 2  | TMI        | A      | B      |        |
+----+------------+--------+--------+--------+
| 3  | TMI        | A      | B      | C      |
+----+------------+--------+--------+--------+
| 4  | TMI        | A      | B      | D      |
+----+------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Back to self referencing table like this:

```
+----+-----------+----------+--------+
| Id | LevelName | ParentId | Level  |
+----+-----------+----------+--------+
| 0  | TMI       |          | Level0 |
+----+-----------+----------+--------+
| 1  | A         | 0        | Level1 |
+----+-----------+----------+--------+
| 2  | B         | 1        | Level2 |
+----+-----------+----------+--------+
| 3  | C         | 2        | Level3 |
+----+-----------+----------+--------+
| 4  | D         | 2        | Level3 |
+----+-----------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: That sample data isn't a denormalised version of your expected results, nor is it hierarchical.

Comment: @Larnu what if there's an `Id` column? (edited the post)

Comment: "I've looked at examples".  You have looked at the examples, but have you tried anything?

Comment: to be honest, I can't even begin to wrap my mind on how I'd get the `parentid` from the first table.. I can get from the second to first, but not first to second..